# Using jQuery to make multiple elements on a page the same height

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function I'm using to make any elements on a page with the class `equalheight` all the same height (the height of the tallest element):

```
equalheight = function(container){

    var currentTallest = 0,
        currentRowStart = 0,
        rowDivs = new Array(),
        $el,
        topPosition = 0;

    $(container).each(function() {
        $el = $(this);
        $($el).height('auto')
        topPostion = $el.position().top;

        if (currentRowStart != topPostion) {
            for (currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) {
                rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
            }
            rowDivs.length = 0; // empty the array
            currentRowStart = topPostion;
            currentTallest = $el.height();
            rowDivs.push($el);
        } else {
            rowDivs.push($el);
            currentTallest = (currentTallest < $el.height()) ? ($el.height()) : (currentTallest);
        }
        for (currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) {
            rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
        }
    });
}

$(window).load(function() {
    equalheight('.equalheight');
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    equalheight('.equalheight');
});
```

The problem I'm running in to is that, let's say I have two rows of boxes. The first row I want all to be the same height, so I give them the class `equalheight`. Okay. Good. Now, I also want the second row of boxes to be all the same height, but just of those boxes in the second row.

Is there any way I can modify this code to allow me to set equal height of multiple groups of elements? For example, maybe something like setting the class as `equalheight1`, `equalheight2`, etc.?

EDIT: One thing I thought about was adding a data attribute on to each element and just calculate the tallest element for each element with the same data attribute..? Like:

```
<div class="equalheight" data-equalgroup="1"> </div>
```

Comment: I think you're close, but will need to define a row class, so you can select groups of .equalHeight objects, rather than all of them at once.  It should be simple to define a container as equalHeightRow, and then only run the code for each set.

Comment: What if, after re-size one `div` fall down, you want that `div` have the same height as the above row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We iterate through all elements and add them to the `currentRow` columns, and updating the maximum height. When we reach an element that its top differs from previous one, we update all heights of `currentRow` columns and then we set `currentRow` to a new one, finally after exiting from the loop, we update the last row columns' height.

```
equalheight = function (container) {
  var currentRow = { cols: [], h: 0 };
  var topPostion = -1;
  $(container).each(function () {
       var $el = $(this);
       $($el).height('auto')
       if (topPostion != $el.position().top) {
            for (var j = 0; j < currentRow.cols.length; j++) {
                currentRow.cols[j].height(currentRow.h);
            }
            topPostion = $el.position().top;
            currentRow = { cols: [], h: 0 };
        }
        currentRow.cols.push($el);
        if ($el.height() > currentRow.h) {
            currentRow.h = $el.height();
        }

  });
  for (var j = 0; j < currentRow.cols.length; j++) {
       currentRow.cols[j].height(currentRow.h);
  }
}
$(window).load(function() {
     equalheight('.equalheight');
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    equalheight('.equalheight');
});
```

here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s5v83cc2/) for it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell you should be able to give each row a different class and simply run the function on each row;

```
$(window).load(function() {
    equalheight('.equalheight-row-1');
    equalheight('.equalheight-row-2');
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    equalheight('.equalheight-row-1');
    equalheight('.equalheight-row-2');
});
```

Although, looking closer at the code it seems to actually take care of that itself (with the `currentRow` stuff).

Edit: You don't actually *have* to give each row a different class, just do this;

```
$('.equalheight-row').each(function () {
    equalheight($(this));
});
```

And the function should run individually on each row.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me it should be as simple as just adding it to the load and resize functions:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    equalheight('.equalheight1');
    equalheight('.equalheight2');
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    equalheight('.equalheight1');
    equalheight('.equalheight2');
});
```

Just note the classname.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a second class to the divs you want to group up.  Something like:

```
<div class="equalheight first"></div>
<div class="equalheight first"></div>
<div class="equalheight second"></div>
<div class="equalheight second"></div>
```

And then in your javascript:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    equalheight('.first.equalheight');
    equalheight('.second.equalheight');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could fix this using flexbox layout, if your target doesn't require IE8 or older.

HTML

```
<div class="rows">
    <div class="cell">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus illo quibusdam, perspiciatis vel officiis alias autem consequuntur labore mollitia omnis natus, fuga, illum id deleniti assumenda amet harum deserunt cum.</div>
    <div class="cell"><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid provident, quaerat ducimus perspiciatis omnis sint aspernatur quibusdam saepe, quam similique eligendi nisi nesciunt atque laudantium quidem, doloribus culpa deserunt laboriosam.</div>
    <div>Aspernatur porro vitae beatae nam fuga nisi magni eaque commodi odio voluptate veritatis laboriosam animi, ullam optio quidem sequi ducimus voluptas quaerat adipisci dignissimos. Velit sequi mollitia nemo veritatis optio.</div></div>
    <div class="cell">Voluptate suscipit, laudantium. A, veniam repellat iste eligendi magnam at nisi quod suscipit laudantium tenetur porro accusamus quam quae nulla voluptatibus molestiae quisquam quos doloremque dolorum ipsam rem. Non, sunt.</div>
    <div class="cell">Tempore praesentium voluptas earum harum numquam consequatur commodi omnis, debitis fuga suscipit, quae repellat hic iure molestiae doloribus. Eveniet voluptate quam placeat fugit iusto consequatur nam eaque porro eligendi itaque.</div>
    <div class="cell">Sed deleniti ullam iusto pariatur natus, voluptatibus iste, ipsum assumenda dolor provident vel eum quisquam odit placeat in eligendi! Doloremque corporis maxime non culpa iusto rerum incidunt excepturi illum veniam.</div>
    <div class="cell">Ullam provident fuga doloremque beatae possimus, facilis veritatis quae officia ut, atque expedita qui nulla adipisci, voluptate quas ipsam dolore vel architecto sapiente tenetur tempora laborum blanditiis libero. Saepe, ad!</div>
    <div class="cell">Molestiae quam impedit sequi suscipit, rerum hic quia saepe excepturi, in assumenda inventore maxime vero. Earum aperiam dicta aut voluptas, rerum, repudiandae modi deserunt minima nostrum recusandae sequi, sunt natus!</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.rows {
    margin: 15px auto;
    width: 960px;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
            -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
                    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.cell {
    min-width: 270px;
    max-width: 275px;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
            -ms-flex: 1;
                    flex: 1;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #F0F0F0;
    margin: 7.5px;
}
```

demo: http://codepen.io/pjetr/pen/wabJYe

Answer (score 1):

I may be going a bit too far out of your depth but if you're using jQuery, why not build a plugin like this?

I'm going to use the same `name` attribute method suggested by Chris Dobson

```
$.fn.equalHeight=function(){
    var $this=$(this);
    heights={};
    function setup(e){
        var n=$(e).attr('name');
        if(!heights[n])heights[n]=[];
        heights[n].push($(e).height());
        //console.log(heights);     
    };
    function getHighest(name){
        return Math.max.apply(null,heights[name]);
    };
    function setHeights(){
        $this.height(getHighest($this.attr('name')));
        //$this.foreach(function(){
           // $this.height(getHighest($(this).attr('name')));
       // });
    };
    $this.each(function(){
        return setup($this);//think I need a return here?
    });
    $('window').on('resize, load',function(){
       setHeights(); 
    });
    setHeights(); 
};
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.equalheight').equalHeight();

});
```

I also used [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781031/use-jquery-css-to-find-the-tallest-of-all-elements) to help in your answer ;)

Might want to get someone to double check it. I'm going to test it as well.

Answer (score 1):

One of the efficient ways to achieve what you want is to divide your task in two functions.

1. Set heights of boxes according to rows in one function
2. Give class names to rows (like equalheight1, equalheight2..) based on top offset in another function.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    equalheight = function () {
        var rowIndex = 1;
        while ($('.equalheight' + rowIndex ).length) {
            var currDivs = [];

            $('.equalheight' + rowIndex ).each(function () {
                currDivs.push($(this).height());
            });

            var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(Math, currDivs);

            $('.equalheight' + rowIndex).each(function () {
                $(this).height(maxHeight);
            });
            rowIndex++;
        }
    };

    assignRows = function () {
        // Reassign classes based on top offset
        var allBoxes = $('.equalheight');
        allBoxes.removeClass();
        var rowIndex = 1;
        var currentRowTop = 0;
        var rowMap = {};

        for (var i = 0; i < allBoxes.length; i++) {
            if (rowMap[$(allBoxes[i]).position().top] === undefined)
                rowMap[$(allBoxes[i]).position().top] = [];
            rowMap[$(allBoxes[i]).position().top].push(allBoxes[i]);
        }

        for (var row in rowMap) {
            for (var i = 0; i < rowMap[row].length; i++) {
                $(rowMap[row][i]).addClass('equalheight equalheight' + rowIndex);
            }
            rowIndex++;
        }
    };

    assignRows();
    equalheight();

    $(window).resize(function () {
        assignRows();
        equalheight();
    });
});
```

In HTML, all boxes would have same class equalheight. For example:

```
<div class="equalheight">Element1</div>
<div class="equalheight">Element2</div>
<div class="equalheight">Element3</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w4j7Lwap/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding <s>an attribute such as name</s>* a new class to the elements - radio buttons use a similar method with the `name` element to determine which buttons are grouped together.

You can use then select by the `equalheight` class and the new class eg. `equal1` to select only the elements from one group and deal with each group separately.

```
<div class="equalheight equal1"></div>
<div class="equalheight equal1"></div>
<div class="equalheight equal2"></div>
<div class="equalheight equal2"></div>
```

then in your JavaScript:

```
var equalGroupOne = $(".equalheight.equal1")
setHeightEqual(equalGroupOne);

var equalGroupTwo = $(".equalheight.equal2")
setHeightEqual(equalGroupTwo);

function setHeightEqual(equalGroup) {
  //Your code here...
}
```

*My initial answer suggested the `name` attribute and jQuery `attributeEquals` selector, but the `name` attribute is not appropriate for `div` elements. An alternate approach is to use HTML5's `data-*` attributes and there is an argument for this being correct, but a new class seemed more appropriate (see my comment below for more).

Comment: The `name` attribute is not valid on a `div` element. Why not just set one more class?

Comment: You're correct, I'll edit my answer. I actually went and did a bit of research about the best option to use instead; initially I thought the `data-*` HTML5 attributes would be most suitable - but they are intended for private data that does not affect layout or presentation (source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184918/best-practice-class-or-data-attribute-as-identifier). So indeed, a new class seems the best in this case.