# Grab the class from an element JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an `li` tag that looks like:

```
<li class="active_fix generator" data-selected="1"></li>
```

Within my `onClick` event I have a `console.log` on `$(this)` and I get back

`[li.active_fix generator]` - among a few things in my console window.

How can I grab the class. So for example save the classname `active_fix` as a `var` but not the second class name `generator`.

```
$('active_fix').on('click', function() {
  console.log($(this));
})
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you describe why you need this? Normally questions about dissecting the `class` attribute are a means to an end that can be better solved another way.

Comment: onLoad I randomly assign classes to elements, then `onClick` I override the class and add another. I needed a way to be able to remember the class that it had to toggle it

Comment: Add the class and also store it in a data attribute. Then you can toggle it on and off based on the value in the data. If you can show the code where you assign the classes I can give you and example of how to do this.

Comment: Ahh that might be a better method thanks @RoryMcCrossan I read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184918/best-practice-class-or-data-attribute-as-identifier and opted to use classes instead of `data-attributes` as the class is only toggling different styles

Answer (score 3):

You can split the class name,

```
$(this).attr("class").split(" ")[0]
```

We are getting the class name using `attr` and splitting the string by a space, then we are getting the first key in the array.

**Reading Material**

[`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

[`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: Thanks man! This worked, i'll have a read of those materials you shared as well

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `.attr("attributeName")` to get its attribute(any),

```
$('.active_fix').on('click', function() {
  console.log($(this).attr("class").split(" ")[0]); //Jquery
  console.log(this.className.split(" ")[0]); //Pure Javascript
});
```

`this.className` will return a string "active_fix generator". Basically multiple classes to an element can be applied by adding a space as a delimiter. So you can split that returned string with `space` to get array of class names. And from that array `[0]` will get you the first class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `classList` to retrieve a list of the elemnent classes:

```js
$('.active_fix').on('click', function() {
  alert(this.classList[0]);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="active_fix generator" data-selected="1">...</li>
```

Comment: Instead of `$(this)[0]` use `this` directly.

Comment: is using `classList` better then using `.split(" ")[0]`

Comment: @DevJuniorThe50421st ClassList seems to be a bit faster than split: http://jsperf.com/classlist-test-n

Comment: Ahh sweet! @Magicprog.fr thanks for the link as well :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.active_fix').on('click', function() {
 alert($(this).attr("class").split(" ")[0]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="active_fix generator" data-selected="1"></li>
```

Answer (score -1):

DevJunior  Try This , It will help you

```
$('.active_fix').on('click', function() {
           console.log($('.active_fix').attr('class').split(' ')[0]);
     });
```

Comment: This was already suggested to the OP a decade ago. Also, inside the callBack function using `$(this)` should be the correct choice. If you use class selector, then it will select all the elements which are having that class and invocation of `.attr()` will be ran over the first element from the collected set.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, Thanks for suggestion

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Your comment about a decade makes no sense. This question was posted today, and the OP has only had an account here for a year.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.active_fix').on('click', function() {
 alert(this.classList[0]);
})
```