# How do I conditionally apply css to a mat-row element on hover?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a table with rows and when a certain condition is met (for each row) the background color is light red.
For every row, on hover, I change the background to light gray.
Problem is, I want the special rows (those that get the light red color already) to be colored with a deeper shade of red on hover (And not gray like all the other rows).

Best result I could get is having the red rows color a single column on hover with deep red but the rest of the row is still painted gray.

.css (without the single column coloring bug):

```
.cheaterRow {
  background-color: rgb(255, 130, 130);
}

.mat-row:hover{
  background-color:rgb(201, 201, 201);
}
```

.html:

```
<table
mat-table
[dataSource]="dataSource"
matSort
matSortActive="score"
matSortDirection="desc"
*ngIf="!loadingData; else loading"
class="row"
>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header 
 class="sortHeader">
        No.
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.id }}</td>
  </ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="name">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Name</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.name | titlecase }}</td>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="level">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Level</mat-label>
      <mat-select (selectionChange)="onChangeLevel($event.value)">
        <mat-option>None</mat-option>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let level of levels" [value]="level.value">
          {{ level.value | titlecase }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
    {{ element.level | titlecase }}
  </td>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="score">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Score</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.score }}</td>
</ng-container>

<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
<tr
  mat-row
  *matRowDef="let row; let even = even; columns: displayedColumns"
  [class.cheaterRow]="isCheater(row.id)"
></tr>
</table>
```

I want the entire row to be colored differently (depending on the condition) on hover.

Comment: just use ngClass when defined the tr, some like `<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;let i=index" [ngClass]="row.position==2?'row special':'row'"></tr>`? in the simple stackblitz:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vfg99a?file=app/table-basic-example.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a data attribute and apply custom css

```
<tr
  mat-row
  *matRowDef="let row; let even = even; columns: displayedColumns"
  class="row"
  [attr.data-isCheater]="isCheater(row.id)"
></tr>
```

*css*

```
.row{
  background:gray
}
.row[data-isCheater='true']:hover{
  background: red
}
```

If you have additional conditions and some rows which match multiple then you can simply organise your css so that conditions you want to take priority lower in the `.css` stylesheet

Comment: why not use [ngClass]?

Comment: yep that would work also, there's a good discussion on classes vs data attributes here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184918/best-practice-class-or-data-attribute-as-identifier

Answer (score 2):

make your last tr  in your table with your customized condtions by writing classes in your css (my css classes are positive ,negative ,cancelled ,highlight)

```
<tr 
     [ngClass]="{'positive' :(row.status?row.status===1:false) , 
      'negative' :(row.status?row.status===2:false)  ,
      'cancelled':(row.status?row.status===4:false),
      'highlight': selectedRowIndex == row}"

        mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">
 </tr>
```