# What's data-sizing in css selector here?

Tags: css

Here's the link to css code I am curious about : https://codepen.io/charlesxiao/pen/NWjgQQm.

Do you know what does the following css code means?

```
.awesome[data-sizing="intrinsic"] {
  width: min-content;
}
```

What's this `data-sizing` attribute? I can't find it anywhere.

Thanks!

Comment: Here is an explanation of data-* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much like how your selectors can target classes (`.class`) and ids (`#id`), your CSS can also target [attributes, including `data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). It's [common practice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) for javascript to target `data-*` attributes rather than going through the rigmarole of adding/removing classes. There's some [particulars choosing between the two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184918/best-practice-class-or-data-attribute-as-identifier/17185039).

`width: min-content;` simply sets the element to the smallest possible size — the word "awesome" is the largest element and that's used as the width.